# Jquery .delay() is not wroking as expected

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery/ajax/php to update my form. After successfully updated the form I'm showing the successful message to `<div id="certainResult"></div>`. Here I added jquery `.delay()` for showing the success message up to few seconds and then it will be fadeout. BUT this `.delay()` is not working somehow. Following is my jquery code:

```
<script>
$("#given_name, #family_name, #work_phone, #mobile_phone, #email, #email_private, #department, #title, #characterNotes").change(function(){

    var cdid =  $("#cdid_hidden").val();
    var family_name =  $("#family_name").val();
    var given_name =  $("#given_name").val();
    var work_phone =  $("#work_phone").val();
    var mobile_phone =  $("#mobile_phone").val();
    var email =  $("#email").val(); 
    var email_private =  $("#email_private").val();
    var department =  $("#department").val();
    var title =  $("#title").val();
    var characterNotes =  $("#characterNotes"). val();


    $.ajax({
      url: 'certainfield.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'html',
      data: {
          "cdid" : cdid,
          "family_name" : family_name,
          "given_name" : given_name,
          "work_phone" : work_phone,
          "mobile_phone" : mobile_phone,
          "email" : email,
          "email_private" : email_private,
          "department" : department,
          "title" : title,
          "characterNotes" : characterNotes
          },
    }).success(function ( data ) {
      getDetails(cdid);       
      $('#certainResult').append(data);   
      $('#certainResult').delay(9000).fadeOut('slow');  

    });        
});
</script>
```

Is there anything bug in my code ?

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: @j08691 just one error which is : `SyntaxError: syntax error

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//E`

Comment: try to put the delay right after the append $('#certainResult').append(data).delay(9000).fadeOut('slow');

Comment: I used this but still not working.

Comment: You have to provide minimalistic sample replicating your issue. BTW, what are you expecting? What means not working?

Comment: @A.Wolff you should carefully read my question. I think I specified my question.

Comment: @creativeartbd do you mean success message fadeOut() without delay? That was my question in fact

Comment: @A.Wolff that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

Instead of using 'delay' use:

```
                    setTimeout(function(){
                      $('#certainResult').fadeOut('slow');    
                    },9000);
```

This will fade out '#certainResult' after a time of 9seconds (9000ms)

Comment: Ok. I'm trying it now.

Comment: No, It's not working. It's still just showing 'bip bip'. I mean show and hide very fast.

Comment: instead of fadeOut('slow') have you tried a number? it could be that it's not recognizing the 'slow' for some reason?

Comment: No, I didn't. But It was ok.

Comment: What do you mean with 'But it was ok.' ? has your issue been resolved or?

Comment: I just mean that I was ok in my pc when I first work on this file. Now there is too many code. I think it's mixed the other code.

Comment: `fadeOut()` is put in fx queue, so delay() should work as expected

Comment: I agree with A. Wolff, does it say anything in the console log, what browser are you testing in?

Comment: There is only error in console log that is : `SyntaxError: syntax error
 

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//E` and I'm using Mozila Firefox.